# Question about subject

Tags: grammar

I cannot understand what is the subject in the following sentences, mainly in the second one 「迂闊に手が出せなくなった・・・・・・」. Is it 「強力な力を持った天魔には」 ? Something like **強力な力を持った天魔には**迂闊に手が出せなくなったのも、当然というものだろう。 ?

> 強力な力を持った天魔には、必然的に他の天魔を統率するという義務が加わる。迂闊に手が出せなくなったのも、当然というものだろう。

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: You have sentences all over there, what exactly are you asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Something like 強力な力を持った天魔には迂闊に手が出せなくなったのも、当然というものだろう。 ?

I'd rather say 他の天魔を統率する義務のある"彼"が/には迂闊に手が出せなくなったのも、当然というものだろう。

The subject and object for [迂闊]{うかつ}に手が出せなくなった are not mentioned here. There's someone who is a 天魔, who now has the duty to 他の天魔を統率する(=to lead other 天魔s) because he's got a 強力な力. It is 当然 that he can't do 迂闊に手を出す(=attack someone thoughtlessly/carelessly. [うかつgoo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/5180/m0u/%E8%BF%82%E9%97%8A/)) because he has the duty to 他の天魔を統率する (I think maybe his situation is like... a schoolboy who has become class president, supposed to keep order in his class and therefore not to pick a fight with another class member...)

---

> 強力な力を持った天魔には、必然的に他の天魔を統率するという義務が加わる。

The relative clause 強力な力を持った modifies 天魔. 必然的に modifies 加わる. 他の天魔を統率するという modifies 義務. I think the 加わる is used as 課せられる("is imposed") here. The sentence has the same structure as:
不動産資産を持つ国民には、必然的に納税するという義務が課せられる。
 
～～には、～～が加わる/課せられる。(To/On ~~, ~~ is added/charged/imposed.)

> 迂闊に手が出せなくなったのも、当然というものだろう。

It can be rephrased as 迂闊に手が出せなくなったのも、当然だろう。(I think the というもの is used as an emphasis.) It has the same structure as:
病気になるのも当然だ。
～～のも当然だ。(It's natural that~~/Naturally~~/No wonder~~)

Comment: 迂闊 is うかつ, not a living thing.

Comment: わ！どうしましょ！私ったら、うかつだったわ！！